# Image is distorting when window is re-sized (CSS)

Tags: css, resize, image-scaling

So I've been trying to create a simple page where the image takes up 100% of the height, with a small sidebar. I want the image to resize itself when I resize the window. When I resize the window vertically, the width stays the same, which is not what I want (I want it to retain it's aspect ratio whatever the window size). I really dislike this distortion, but am unsure of how to fix it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
.big-image {
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I just set the width to auto instead, but it still distorts the image when I resize the window to make it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

set `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to your `.big-image` class, in order for the `max-height` and `min-width` property to work. These properties, along with `height`, `width`, `min-height`, `max-width`, `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` doesn't work on inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can set either the `height` or `width` of an image to `auto` and control the other property with a set size whether that be percentage or px. That `auto` should maintain the aspect ratio of the image while you get to control the size of the image with the other property.

Answer (score 0):

`max-width:100%` and `height:auto` will work. When applying max-width:1000%; it will take the width of the container and height will be proportionately varied.